# Why would OpenSSL be returning a different SHA1 hash output in my terminal?

Tags: hash, openssl, rsa, sha1, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to hash a fairly small value using SHA1 for a university excercise.

I'm running OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018. Operating System is Ubuntu 18.04.1, running through Windows Subsystem for Linux 1.

Running any of the following;

```sh
echo "361448504617" | openssl dgst -SHA1
echo 361448504617 | openssl dgst -SHA1
openssl dgst -sha1 hash.txt
openssl SHA1 hash.txt
```

Returns:

```
(stdin)= f98a0e600cd960f6c414343748a8dabc5ae9ec0a
(stdin)= f98a0e600cd960f6c414343748a8dabc5ae9ec0a
SHA1(hash.txt)= f98a0e600cd960f6c414343748a8dabc5ae9ec0a
SHA1(hash.txt)= f98a0e600cd960f6c414343748a8dabc5ae9ec0a
```

If I go to an online SHA1 hash generator, such as https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha1-hash-generator/, it returns:

```
A599EBBA6735313C848118F6EDB63012163D7581
```

Which is also the answer to the worksheet, and also what the labratory instructors terminal returns.

Can anyone give me a hand in troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annnd, I figured it out.

OpenSSL was hashing the newline character also, pretty easy to solve using the -n argument for echo.

```
echo -n 361448504617 | openssl SHA1
```

Also, when OpenSSL was reading from file, I got the same error because vim was saving with an end of line character. Fixed by running the following commands inside vim:

```
:set binary 
:set noeol 
:wq
```